# Terence Tao Exercise 5.4.8: Boundedness of Limit.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $ \{ a_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be a Cauchy sequence of rationals, and let $x$ 
be a real number. Show that if $a_{n} \leq x $ for all $n \geq 1 $, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} \leq x $.

Comment: What have you tried? By the way, the reference in the title is far from being totally clear and complete.

Comment: The hint is given to use the contradiction method, in which I assumed that lim is > x. so, there must exist a real no z which lie b/w x and lim an, but after that I dont know ow to contradict.

Comment: @user3135030 well my answer is exactly what you just described.

Comment: Often a good idea for proofs like this is to attempt an argument by contradiction, and pick a suitable $\epsilon$ value. In your case, if you picked $\epsilon = a - x > 0$, where you assumed $a_n \rightarrow a > x$, you're going to find the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the concept of REAL LIMIT is not introduced until chapter 6, the (ε, N)-definition cannot be used to prove this. The hint is given to use contradiction and Prop 5.4.9, here's my proof using these two:

suppose $a=LIM_{n\to ∞}a_n>x$, there exists a rational $q$ that $a>q>x$ due to Prop 5.4.14. Since $\forall n≥1,a_n≤x<q$, construct a sequence $(q-a_n)$, it's trivial to prove the sequence is Cauchy and it's *non-negative* using Prop 5.4.9, that is, $$LIM_{n\to ∞}(q-a_n)=LIM_{n\to ∞}q-LIM_{n\to ∞}a_n=q-a≥0$$so $q≥a$, which contradicts $a>q$, deduced from the original hypothesis.

Comment: How can a Q about the limit of a  real sequence be  answered without any concept of a  real limit? Reminds me of an Ontario high school text that introduced derivatives  two chapters before mentioning or defining limits.

Comment: @user254665 because the LIM symbol used to define real numbers from rational sequences is **meaningless** before chapter 6, like the placeholder '-' used to define integers from naturals in chapter 4. Just get rid of the knowledge of these 'obvious' concept in high school or college when reading tao's real analysis

Answer (score 1):

Since $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, [it is converging](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214179/every-cauchy-sequence-in-the-reals-converges) to some $a\in\Bbb R$. Now, if $a>x$, then there exists $N$ such that $|a_N-a|<\frac{a-x}{2}$ and we get the contradiction:
$$\frac{x-a}{2}<a_N-a \qquad \implies \qquad x <\frac{x+a}{2}<a_N$$

Comment: Hi Surb, can you explain why $|a_{N}-a| < \frac {a-x}{2}$

Comment: @user3135030 By definition of convergence: $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. Set $n=N$ and $\epsilon = (a-x)/2$ (which is $>0$ because $a>x$ by assumption).

Comment: Ahh, it was stupid of me to ask this question, you took this real value to contradict.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I like @bigtit answer. However, the question says the solution could be arrived at using Corollary 5.4.10, and this is my attempt using this corollary.
Let's proceed by contradiction and prove the statement: 
$$ \forall n \ge1, a_n \le x \Rightarrow LIM_{n\to \infty} a_n > x  $$
Since $x\in \Bbb R$ and $a = LIM_{n\to \infty} a_n  $ we know there exists $ q\in \Bbb Q  $ such that  $x < q < a$. By hypothesis $$ \forall n \ge1, q > x \Rightarrow q>a_n $$ Since $q \in \Bbb Q$ it can also be expressed as the Cauchy sequence $ LIM_{n\to \infty} q_n $. Applying Corollary 5.4.10: 
$$ \forall n \ge1,  q_n> a_n \Rightarrow LIM_{n\to \infty} q_n >  LIM_{n\to \infty} a_n$$ 
Thus $q = q_n > LIM_{n\to \infty} a_n $, a contradiction. Thus our initial statement is false.