# Inequalities with Cauchy sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, cauchy-sequences

I'm reading this question ([Terence Tao Exercise 5.4.8: Boundedness of Limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558189/terence-tao-exercise-5-4-8-boundedness-of-limit)) regarding the proof a property of Cauchy sequences. However, I don't understand a step in the proof,

> ... suppose $a = \text{LIM}_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n >x$, there exists a rational $q$ that $a>q>x$ due to Prop 5.4.14. Since $\forall n\geq 1,a_n\leq x<q$, construct a sequence $(q−an)$, it's trivial to prove the sequence is Cauchy and it's **non-negative**...

I don't understand why is $(q−a_n)$ *non-negative*, because,
$$a_n\leq x<q, \qquad n\geq 1,$$
$$\Rightarrow a_n<q ,$$
$$\Rightarrow 0<(q-a_n).$$

Hence the sequence is strictly  *positive*, this is critical in the next step because the following theorem is valid for *non-negative* sequences only.

I'm also confused with the use of the "$\geq$" and "$>$" in a few proofs of real analysis,  for example in page ([117](https://books.google.com.co/books/content?id=ecTsDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U17BoE-K6lzkkmYurVqmYXL5eJeSw&w=1280),[118](https://books.google.com.co/books/content?id=ecTsDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA118&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U2vKhNGj5OTovo7UAUHe_-kTTyUOw&w=1280)) of Terence Tao [Analysis I](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=ecTsDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), when he  proves the **(Existence of least upper bound)**, he performs the following step,

> [image: Terry Tao book, (Existence of least upper bound)]

How can he conclude that,

$$\Big| \frac{m_n}{n} - \frac{m_{n}}{n'} \Big|\leq \frac{1}{N} \quad \text{for all  } \quad n,n' \geq N\geq 1,$$

since in a previous equation he had:

$$ \frac{m_n}{n} - \frac{m_{n}}{n'} > -\frac{1}{N} $$

Can one just put the  "$\geq$" instead of the "$>$" ?

Comment: You already said that $$\frac{m_n}{n}-\frac{m_n}{n'}>-\frac{1}{N}.$$ So, it must be clear then that $$\frac{m_n}{n}-\frac{m_n}{n'}\geq-\frac{1}{N}$$ is a true statement. Remember the definition of the disjunction of two propositions?

Comment: Just like $3>2$ and so there is no problem by writing $3\geq 2$.

Comment: I understand, the problem is the other way around, starting from a statement where $\leq$ and claim that it is a $<$. Just as you said, the disjunction of two propositions.