# Proving formal limits are genuine limits

Tags: real-analysis

Am asking in the hopes that someone has read Tao's book and can explain his proof outline; this question comes from Tao's Analysis 1. The proposition being proved is:

> **Proposition 6.1.15** (Formal limits are genuine limits). Suppose that $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers. Then $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n$, i.e. $$\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n.$$

The outline he provides is as follows, with the bolded part being the part I do not understand:

> Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence of rationals, and write $L:=\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n$. We have to show that $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $L$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. **Assume for the sake of contradiction that sequence $a_n$ is *not* eventually $\varepsilon$-close to $L$. Use this**, and the fact that $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is Cauchy, to show that there is an $N\geq m$ such that either $a_n>L+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$, or $a_n>L-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$. Then use Exercise 5.4.8.

My issue with his proof outline is that I do not see where contradiction comes into play. We are essentially showing that there exists some $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n-L|<\frac\varepsilon2$, in other words, that $(a_n)$ converges to $L$. This can be shown from the fact that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, as all Cauchy sequences converge. I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain how Tao's proof is supposed to work, thank you.

Potentially relevant definitions:

> **Definition 5.3.1** (Real numbers). A *real number* is defined to be an object of the form $\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n$, where $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers. Two real numbers $\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}b_n$ are said to be equal iff $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are equivalent Cauchy sequences.
>
> **Definition 6.1.5** (Convergence of sequences). Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a real number, and let $L$ be a real number. A sequence $(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$ of real numbers is said to be $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ iff $a_n$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ for every $n\geq N$, i.e., we have $|a_n-L|\leq\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. We say that a sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is eventually $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ iff there exists an $N\geq m$ such that $(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $L$. We say that a sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $L$ iff it is eventually $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ for every real $\varepsilon>0$.
>
> **Definition 6.1.8** (Limits of sequences). If a sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to some real number $L$, we say that $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is convergent and that its limit is $L$; we write $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$ to denote this fact.

Comment: It seems either you stopped copying the proof before you got to the contradiction, or the contradiction is implied by Exercise 5.4.8, whatever that said.

Comment: So it could be helpful to copy the statement of Exercise 5.4.8 as well. (The solution is probably not needed.) Also to say how the notation $LIM$ is defined. In the current form of your question, I think only people who have easy access to the book can answer it.

Comment: @DavidK *Exercise 5.4.8* Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence of rationals, and let $x$ be a real number. Show that if $a_n\leq x$ for all $n\geq1$, then $\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq x$. Similarly, show that if $a_n\geq x$ for all $n\geq1$, then $\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n\geq x$. (Also, what I've posted above is Tao's outline; writing a full proof is an exercise for the reader)

Comment: Ok, I think this is your Exercise 5.4.8: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558189/terence-tao-exercise-5-4-8-boundedness-of-limit - except the person who posted it did not take care to distinguish between lim and LIM, which is the point here.

Comment: Right, so my first guess (incomplete copy) was wrong, second guess (it’s in the Exercise) was correct. The exercise does lead to a contradiction, but as you say, Tao makes you find it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consequence of the assumption in the bold-faced text is the following:

> there is an $N\geq m$ such that either $a_n>L+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$, or $a_n>L-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$.

So now there are two possible cases arising from the assumption:

Case $a_n>L+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$. 
Then you can use Exercise 5.4.8 (possibly after some renaming/renumbering of the relevant sequence so it matches the conditions of the exercise) to show that 
$$
\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n
 \geq L+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},
$$
contradicting the premise that 
$L:=\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n.$

Case $a_n>L-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$
Then you can use Exercise 5.4.8 to show that
$$
\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n
 \leq L-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},
$$
again contradicting the premise that 
$L:=\operatorname{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n.$

Since you get a contradiction either way, the assumption leads to a contradiction.

Perhaps you can make a direct proof. But this one does indeed work by contradiction.